# Correct placement of API call within MVC ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-core

I'm looking for some advice any feedback would be great.

The outline of the app i'm making is a weather checker. A user inputs a postcode into the view. This postcode will then be used to gain longitude and latitude from an API, the results would then be fed into another API which would return the weather information.

I'll be using the HttpClient class to achieve this.

Am I correct in reasoning that the API calls should be made within the model and not the controller?

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried. We need to see some code in order to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "within model" ? Your code still will be invoked in controller, just will be written in other class or something to don't mess controller (and to follow SRP principle). If you mean this, yeah, go ahead and place API calls in separeted classes (they should be asynchronous). And use DI to not rely on specific implementation.

Comment: Put your API call in different class as suggested and just call it something like WeatherService and then use it where ever you require it.  Models should just be plain objects  and controllers clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct in reasoning that the API calls should be made within the model and not the controller?

Your reasoning is correct. Your API calls should not be made in the controller - as this logic does not pertain to the view.

However, as suggested in other comments, I would place the calls in a service like:

```
public class ApiCallsService : IApiCallsService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public ApiCallsService(DbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<string> CallApi(string data)
    {
        //... call the API and return a string with the results
    }
}
```

Your interface would then look like this:

```
public interface IApiCallsService
{
    Task<string> CallApi(string data);
}
```

You would then need to add the service to your Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddTransient<IApiCallsService, ApiCallsService>();
}
```

Then, to call the api from your controller:

```
namespace WeatherApp.Web.Controllers
{
    public class WeatherController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IApiCallsService _apiService;

        public WeatherController(IApiCallsService apiService)
        {
            _apiService = apiService;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            // Call the API
            string result = await _apiService.CallApi(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great answer.